# Clickhouse, create dictionary with decimal type

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I try to create a clickhouse dictionary:

```
CREATE DICTIONARY rnd.exchange_rate_history (
    code String,
    date Date,
    rate Decimal(20, 6)
)
PRIMARY KEY code, date...
```

But I get an error:

> Unknown type Decimal(20, 6) (version 20.6.3.28 (official build))

What should I do to create dictionary with this structure?

Comment: Did you tray UInt64 instead of Decimal(20,6)?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works!

Comment: Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: UInt64 can be used in dictionaries.

Comment: Decimal type has 2 notations Decimal(20, 6) == Decimal32(6). Someone missed to implement the first one in dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use types with fixed precision, such as [Decimal32](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/decimal/):

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY test.test_dict_01
(
    `code` String,
    `date` Date,
    `rate` Decimal32(6)
)
PRIMARY KEY code, date
SOURCE(FILE(PATH 'opt/dicts/test.csv'))
LIFETIME(MIN 0 MAX 300)
LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED())
```

---

It looks like a bug, could you create the issue in https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues?